# Active class for button groups in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to switch the 'active' class on a a button group on ReactJs. I am trying to avoid the use of JQuery here and trying to figure out how it could be achieved with React. Any help much appreciated. The code:

```
class TimelineNav extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="TimelineNav">
        <button href="#" className="allFilter active">All</button>
        <button href="#" className="professionalFilter">Professional</button>
        <button href="#" className="academicFilter">Academic</button>
        <button href="#" className="miscFilter">Miscellaneous</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it, though there are some ways to make this more efficient / elegant

```
class TimelineNav extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      'active': 0
    };
  }

  setActive( index ) {
    this.setState({ 'active': index });
  }

  render() {
    var current = this.state.active;
    var getClass = function( name, index ) {
      if ( index === current )
        return name + ' active';
      return name;
    };
    return(
      <div className="TimelineNav">
        <button href="#" onClick={this.setActive.bind(this, 0)} className={getClass("allFilter",0)}>All</button>
        <button href="#" onClick={this.setActive.bind(this, 1)} className={getClass("professionalFilter",1)}>Professional</button>
        <button href="#" onClick={this.setActive.bind(this, 2)} className={getClass("academicFilter",2)}>Academic</button>
        <button href="#" onClick={this.setActive.bind(this, 3)} className={getClass("miscFilter",3)}>Miscellaneous</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `react-router` to manage browser history they already have something cooked into `Link` for that. It's nice and simple they way it works.

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/active-links/app.js

Answer (score 0):

I like this suggestion From PluralSight:
The simplest approach is to use a ternary statement inside of a template literal.

Here is there example:

```
import React from "react";

const Banner = ({ active, children }) => (
  <div className={`banner ${active ? "active" : ""}`}>{children}</div>
);

export default Banner;
```

Link: https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/applying-classes-conditionally-react